# Making multi-step form by changing HTML content with ajax do not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I try to implement multi-step form with changing HTML content...

HTML id current will be replaced with similar content from Form2..etc

First form:

```
<form  method="post" class="newsletter">
    <div id="current">
        <div class="fce-newsletter-form">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                    <h2 class="mb-half"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_title')?></h2>
                    <p class="mb-2 lead">Mit unserem Newsletter erhalten Sie monatlich Informationen rund um das Urlaubsland Österreich und eine Auswahl exklusiver Angebote und Gutscheine!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="testFormChange">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="custom-input-newsletter" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail Adresse *" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="" class="fce-newsletter-form-button btn btn-block btn-primary" id="customButton" value="Weiter">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="step1" name="step">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-note">mit * gekennzeichnete Felder bitte ausfüllen.</p>
                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-error-message"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
$('#customButton').on('click', function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {"action": "testNewsletter"},
            dataType: "html",
            success:function(data) {

                $("#current").empty();
                $("#current").html(data);

            }
        });
    });
```

Custom function in functions.php on replacing content (for example from form1 to form2, from form2 to form3 and etc..) :

```
function testNewsletter() {

    global $idForm;


    switch($idForm) {
        case 1 : echo include ('pages/forms/form-two.php'); $idForm+=1; break;
        case 2: echo include ('pages/forms/form-three.php'); $idForm+=1 ; break;
        default: break;
    }



   wp_die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_testNewsletter', 'testNewsletter'); // add action for logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_testNewsletter', 'testNewsletter' ); // add action for unlogged users
```

For example content Form2 I would like to replace:

```
<div class="fce-newsletter-form">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
            <h2 class="mb-half"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_title')?></h2>
            <p class="mb-3 lead">Bitte verraten Sie uns Ihren Namen.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <select id="gender" class="custom-select">
                                <option value="sf">Herr</option>
                                <option value="sf">Frau</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Vorname" id="newsletterName" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="" class="form-control" placeholder="Nachname" id="newsletterSurname">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="submit" class="fce-newsletter-form-button btn btn-block btn-primary" id="customButton"  value="Weiter">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-note text-center">mit * gekennzeichnete Felder bitte ausfüllen</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck_form_One">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_form_One">Ja, ich akzeptiere die AGBs der Österreich Werbung *</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Switch from Form1 to Form2 works, but when I want to continue, Java Script is not recognized for Form2 (probably is not initialized). Button id is still same for all Forms.  Anyone know how to solve that? Do I have good proposal actually?

Thanks for the advice

Comment: can you post your form-two code?

Comment: @Vel thank you for answer, I have edited question with code for Form2

Comment: you need to change `type="submit"` to button in step 2

Comment: @Vel   I tried that, page is not refreshed, but It does not switch me from form2 to form3..can you please give me advice, why ?

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: I code with your script, switch from form-one to form-two works, but . from form-two to form-three no, Do I need to do something with form-three content?

Comment: did you change `type="submit" ` to button?

Comment: did you increase `global $idForm;` value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181287/discussion-between-matus-vrsansky-and-vel).

Comment: <input type="button" class="fce-newsletter-form-button btn btn-block btn-primary customButton"   value="Weiter"> as you recommended me,, also in functions.php $idForm is 2, but nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change input type submit to button in step 2 form and add the below script.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('click','#customButton', function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>',
            type: "POST",
            data: {"action": "testNewsletter"},
            dataType: "html",
            success:function(data) {

                jQuery("#current").empty();
                jQuery("#current").html(data);

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```